# Joomla Cache issues

Tags: caching, joomla, mariadb

I get 500 Internal server error several times on some pages, since my site was moved to a new server.
The problem automatically resolves after a few seconds (sometimes several seconds).
also when I clear joomla page cache, the problem resolves.
After installing jotcache and replace it with joomla page cache issues resolves but I want to use joomla page cache; because it's faster.
How can I fix this problem?

Joomla 3.8.2 ; 
PHP 5.6 ; 
MariaDB 10.2 (in old server mysql 5.5 )

Comment: If your getting HTTP500 errors what does your error log say? Did you try to increase the error reporting? https://www.svenbluege.de/joomla-event-gallery/event-gallery-manual/faq-blank-page

Comment: Nothing in error log, and with maximum error reporting No errors seen

Comment: Strange. You see error so I would assume log entries. Do you still get those 500 errors?

Comment: Yes, If I active joomla page cache, get those 500 errors again

Comment: Can you check with your hosting provider to get some error logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using progressive caching, which is the [worst type of Joomla caching](https://www.itoctopus.com/progressive-caching-in-joomla-3-is-a-recipe-for-disaster) and you most likely do not need it. Switch to Joomla conservative caching and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Seems fixed after Switch to Joomla conservative caching,

Comment: But why before I don't have this problem?

Comment: It seems that the algorithm for progressive caching got worse in Joomla 3.8.